Can I fill this hole in my basement slab?
What is this hole in by basement floor? It is approximately the size of the drain pipe next to it, but it's full of dirt/rubble and has a metal bar protruding from it. The home is a 1911 American foursquare located in Minnesota.



If I don't need this hole for anything, how should I go about filling it in? I'd like to seal it up in case it is allowing radon into the basement.

What's at the other end of the bar? We can't see that from here, and you'll want to know before you bury it forever. My wild hunch is a water valve. Howdy from St. Cloud.

Clean out the dirt and rubble real good and take another picture.

Before doing something your may regret later based on a radon worry, why don't you have a radon test done. In some areas the local building department or sometimes the health department will do them for free.

My bad, I meant to add more photos on the original post. Here you can see how deep it is, as well as the remaining debris that was too heavy for my shopvac. I did manage to clean out quite a bit of lighter junk. I'll note that this is about 12' from my newer (one of a few that have been switched to copper on my block) water main.

@RMDman thanks for the suggestion. We did have a radon test performed before purchasing the home, and have since installed a monitor. We have been hovering between 1.5 and 2.5, but it sometimes spikes closer to 4 so I'm only casually looking for ways to improve the situation.

it looks like water valve

If it's a water valve, you should be able to turn the rod.

The rod does not turn with substantial torque and the hole is not located near my water main, but it is close to the sanitary line. Someone suggested that it may be an old internal rainwater drain, or perhaps just an old 4" drain. The rod is definitely unusual

After some more thought and research, I'm wondering if it is an old sewer shut-off valve. I'm on a hill and wouldn't be concerned with backflow from the street, but the location, use of a 4" pipe for access, and rod shaped like a handle all make sense.
